# How can I import data from AWS s3 to dynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

How can I import data from AWS s3 from the public data set  [This link, this is a public dataset](https://registry.opendata.aws/) to dynamoDB?

I have tried many ways to import the data, aws pipeline, aws athena, none of them worked. I also tried using the node.js to import the data, it did not work. I also downloaded the public dataset into my laptop, but I can not find a import button in the dynamoDB website.

Could you guys recommend an efficient and less cost way to import date from the s3 to dynamoDB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With the release on 18 August 2022 of the Import from S3 [feature built into](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.HowItWorks.html) DynamoDB, I'd use AWS Glue to transform the file into the format the feature needs and then use it to import into the new table. It charges by the GB processed, not capacity like it would if you did this yourself with code. It also adds all errors and info to CloudWatch.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me pushing 90k records.

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
    AWS.config.region = process.env.AWS_REGION 
    const s3 = new AWS.S3()

    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
    const ddbTable = "your-table" 

    // The Lambda handler
    exports.handler = async (event) => {
      console.log (JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
      console.log('Using DDB table: ', ddbTable)

      await Promise.all(
        event.Records.map(async (record) => {
          try {
            console.log('Incoming record: ', record)

            // Get original text from object in incoming event
            const originalText = await s3.getObject({
              Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
              Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key
            }).promise()

            // Upload JSON to DynamoDB
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(originalText.Body.toString('utf-8'))
            await ddbLoader(jsonData)

          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
          }
        })
      )
    }

    // Load JSON data to DynamoDB table
    const ddbLoader = async (data) => {
      // Separate into batches for upload
      let batches = []
      const BATCH_SIZE = 25

      while (data.length > 0) {
        batches.push(data.splice(0, BATCH_SIZE))
      }

      console.log(`Total batches: ${batches.length}`)

      let batchCount = 0

      // Save each batch
      await Promise.all(
        batches.map(async (item_data) => {

          // Set up the params object for the DDB call
          const params = {
            RequestItems: {}
          }
          params.RequestItems[ddbTable] = []
  
          item_data.forEach(item => {
            for (let key of Object.keys(item)) {
              // An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string
              if (item[key] === '') 
                delete item[key]
            }

            // Build params
            params.RequestItems[ddbTable].push({
              PutRequest: {
                Item: {
                  ...item
                }
              }
            })
          })

          // Push to DynamoDB in batches
          try {
            batchCount++
            console.log('Trying batch: ', batchCount)
            const result = await docClient.batchWrite(params).promise()
            console.log('Success: ', result)
          } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error: ', err)
          }
        })
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom script to download the data and insert it record by record into DynamoDB. You can use the `batchWriteItem` api to insert multiple records (up to 25) in a single api call. Note this still consumes 1 write capacity unit per record inserted (assuming records are < 1k).

AWS Data Migration service can also do this for you, but your own script will cost nothing (outside of DynamoDB provisioned writes).

Comment: Thank you very much, I found a tutorial on youtube. It shows me how to use python to import the data into dynamoDB.